# How to enable users to down-vote in this simple voting counter (that uses the post meta)?

Tags: plugin-development, post-meta, ajax

[This simple tutorial](http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/simple-voting-for-wordpress-with-php-and-jquery/) teaches you how to make a voting counter using the post's meta data.

I would like to know how to add down-votes to this small script (e.g. -1, -2).
In the following way: If the post has 0 votes and it gets down-voted, it ends up with -1. If the post has 1 vote and it is down-voted it ends up with 0 (only one counter).

**the jQuery part:**

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ) ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".vote a").click(

            function() {
                var some = jQuery(this);
                var thepost = jQuery(this).attr("post");
                var theuser = jQuery(this).attr("user");
                jQuery.post("<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/vote.php", {
                    user: theuser,
                    post: thepost
                }, function(data) {
                    var votebox = ".vote" + thepost + " span";
                    jQuery(votebox).text(data);
                    jQuery(some).replaceWith('<span class="voted">Voted</span>');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

> When a member clicks on the vote link,
>   the above code will get the post ID
>   and the member’s user ID and send it
>   to a file called vote.php using a post
>   method. The vote.php file will perform
>   everything we need to add the vote.

**vote.php:**

```
<?php
$file = dirname(__FILE__);
$file = substr($file, 0, stripos($file, "wp-content") );

require( $file . "/wp-load.php");

$currentvotes = get_post_meta($_POST['post'], 'votes', true);
$currentvotes = $currentvotes + 1;

$voters = get_post_meta($_POST['post'], 'thevoters', true);
if(!$voters) $voters = $_POST['user']; else $voters = $voters.",".$_POST['user'];

update_post_meta($_POST['post'], 'votes', $currentvotes);
update_post_meta($_POST['post'], 'thevoters', $voters);

echo $currentvotes;
?>
```

> Once the information is posted to
>   vote.php two custom fields are
>   created. One to count the vote and one
>   to add the voter to a list so that
>   they can’t vote again.

**functions.php:**

```
// voting function
function voting($id) {
global $user_ID;
$currentvotes = get_post_meta($id, 'votes', true);
$voters = get_post_meta($id, 'thevoters', true);
$voters = explode(",", $voters);
foreach($voters as $voter) {
    if($voter == $user_ID) $alreadyVoted = true;
}

if(!$currentvotes) $currentvotes = 0;
echo '<div class="vote vote'.$id.'"><span>'.$currentvotes.'</span>';
if($user_ID && !$alreadyVoted) echo '<br /><a post="'.$id.'" user="'.$user_ID.'">'.__("Vote").'</a>';
if($user_ID && $alreadyVoted) echo '<br /><span class="voted">'.__("Voted").'</span>';
echo '</div>';
if(!$user_ID) echo '<div class="signup"><p><a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-login.php?action=register">'.__('Register').'</a> '.__('to vote').'.</p></div>';
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Loading script(s) directly in the theme's header.php... a puppy just died... :(

Comment: @t31os haha, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make a second button for down voting. Give the upvote button a class of up and the down vote button a class of down.

jQuery

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ) ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".vote a.up").click(

            function() {
                var some = jQuery(this);
                var thepost = jQuery(this).attr("post");
                var theuser = jQuery(this).attr("user");
                jQuery.post("<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/vote.php", {
                    user: theuser,
                    post: thepost,
                    updown: 'up'
                }, function(data) {
                    var votebox = ".vote" + thepost + " span";
                    jQuery(votebox).text(data);
                    jQuery(some).replaceWith('<span class="voted">Voted</span>');
                });
            });
            jQuery(".vote a.down").click(

            function() {
                var some = jQuery(this);
                var thepost = jQuery(this).attr("post");
                var theuser = jQuery(this).attr("user");
                jQuery.post("<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/vote.php", {
                    user: theuser,
                    post: thepost,
                    updown: 'down'
                }, function(data) {
                    var votebox = ".vote" + thepost + " span";
                    jQuery(votebox).text(data);
                    jQuery(some).replaceWith('<span class="voted">Voted</span>');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

vote.php

```
<?php
$file = dirname(__FILE__);
$file = substr($file, 0, stripos($file, "wp-content") );

require( $file . "/wp-load.php");

$currentvotes = get_post_meta($_POST['post'], 'votes', true);
if("up" == $_POST['updown']) {
    $currentvotes ++;
} elseif("down" == $_POST['updown']) {
    $currentvotes --;
}

$voters = get_post_meta($_POST['post'], 'thevoters', true);
if(!$voters) $voters = $_POST['user']; else $voters = $voters.",".$_POST['user'];

update_post_meta($_POST['post'], 'votes', $currentvotes);
update_post_meta($_POST['post'], 'thevoters', $voters);

echo $currentvotes;
?>
```

Thats all you should need to edit

Comment: I'd like to add that this voting system can easily be abused. The only real way to secure it would be to force people to be logged into to vote. Once logged in you should check the users username in the vote.php rather than passing it in the ajax request.